# Access local process from local cluster

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes, local, docker-desktop

I have a local Kubernetes Cluster running under Docker Desktop on Mac. I am running another docker-related process locally on my machine (a local insecure registry). I am interested in getting a process inside the local cluster to push/pull images from the local docker registry.

How can I expose the local registry to be reachable from a pod inside the local Kubernetes cluster?

A way to do this would be to have both the Docker Desktop Cluster and the docker registry use the same docker network. Adding the registry to an existing network is easy.
How does one add the Docker Desktop Cluster to the network?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/), could you check that? Also found [tutorial](https://medium.com/htc-research-engineering-blog/setup-local-docker-repository-for-local-kubernetes-cluster-354f0730ed3a) for that. Let me know if that answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments

I think what you're looking for is mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/). You would have to add your local insecure registry as insecure-registries value in docker for desktop. Then after restart you should be able to use it.

### Deploy a plain HTTP registry

> This procedure configures Docker to entirely disregard security for your registry. This is very insecure and is not recommended. It exposes your registry to trivial man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks. Only use this solution for isolated testing or in a tightly controlled, air-gapped environment.
>
> Edit the daemon.json file, whose default location is /etc/docker/daemon.json on Linux or C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json on Windows Server. If you use Docker Desktop for Mac or Docker Desktop for Windows, click the Docker icon, choose Preferences (Mac) or Settings (Windows), and choose Docker Engine.
>
> If the daemon.json file does not exist, create it. Assuming there are no other settings in the file, it should have the following contents:

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["myregistrydomain.com:5000"]
}
```

---

Also found a tutorial for that on medium with macOS. Take a look [here](https://medium.com/htc-research-engineering-blog/setup-local-docker-repository-for-local-kubernetes-cluster-354f0730ed3a).

Answer (score 0):

Is running the registry inside the kubernetes cluster an option?

That way you can use a NodePort service and push images to an address like

- "localhost:9000/myrepo".

This is significant because Docker allows insecure (non SSL) connections for localhost.